# regex replace span element with its contents

Tags: regex, html-parsing

Text:

```
god is a <span class="linkText0" name="name1">good</span> god my <span class="linkText1" name="name2">friend</span>
```

Expected (remove `<span>..</span>` given the `name` matches)

```
god is a good god my <span class="linkText1" name="name2">friend</span>
```

My Regex:

```
/<span[^]+name=\"name2\">([^]+)</span>/g
```

Results:

```
god is a friend
```

http://regexr.com?36fbh

Please help to correct

Comment: Please don't use regex to parse (or manipulate) HTML. The <center> cannot hold. Zalgo is Tony the Pony, he comes! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Your regex and your expectation doesn't match...Your expectation removes span named "name1", yet your regex looks for "name2". If you're looking for "name1": http://regexr.com?36fbk **BUT** again, you shouldn't use RegExp to manipulate HTML.

Comment: It should be `/<span[^<>]+name=\"name2\">([^<>]+)</span>/g` ... **WARNING** Not Responsible For any Damages caused by using regex to parse html

Comment: Thanks @Anirudh . I have a situation where i am forming my own dom, hence no chances of failure. Please put your comment as an answer so that I can mark it correct.

Comment: If you are creating your own HTML, then why don't create the HTML without the offending <span> tags?

Comment: What language are you using? And What is your expected result text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex

```
/<span[^<>]+name=\"name2\">([^<>]+)</span>/g
```

`[^<>]` would match anything except `<` or `>`

Though you should use an html parser.